# How to show start time and end time in month view for all day events?

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to show event start time and and end time with title for the all day events in month view.

is there any method or property available in fullcalendar.io which can help me to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, use the **eventRender** callback (see its description in [docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/)).

```
function( event, element, view ) { ... }
```

You have 2 options to do what you need:

1. Modify the `element` that is being passed to the eventRender callback by changing its HTML.

From the docs:

> **element** is a newly created jQuery element that will be used for rendering. It has already been populated with the correct time/title text.

2. Or, you can construct a custom element that fits your requirements and return it from the callback. Make sure to to return a `<td>` element for your all-day events:

> The function can also return a brand new element that will be used for rendering instead. For all-day background events, you must be sure to return a `<td>`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am able to capture that event but still not able to get the time component of that event which is required to show the Time in "All Day" events (my original issue). Tried to parse the start property (moment) but sometimes it is giving me 12:00 AM and that is not correct.

Comment: @IntekhabSheikh It's hard to tell without seeing your code. Could you create a plunkr with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You may use eventRender as below

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        defaultView: 'month',
        editable: true,
        events: events,
        eventRender: function (calEvent, element, view) {
//In my case I've created properties startTimeShort  and endTimeShort 
            element.html("<span>" + calEvent.startTimeShort + "-" + calEvent.endTimeShort + "</span>");
            
        }

    });
```